# Windows XP Mode loading in small screen in vmware player

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I am running windows 7. I have just finished downloading and converting (using vmware converter) the Windows XP Mode vmware image to a .vmx file for vmware player.

I can then play the Windows XP image fine in VMWare player. There is however and issue where the windows xp screen inside vmware does not take up the whole screen. In face it only takes up a very small area. I've read on some forums that this might be a compatibility issue between windows 7 and windows xp.

Does anyone know how to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `VMWare Tools` on the guest XP machine and bounce it. It contains several virtualization drivers among them one for the virtual graphic card. This allows you to dynamically change the screen resolution of the guest, just by resizing the VMWare Player window.